# R: Plotting a shapefile, plots the shapefile many times, not just once

Tags: r, shapefile, polygon, plot, spatial-analysis

I am trying to make a map using a particular shapefile as the first layer.  The shapefile has multiple attributes and when I plot it, the plot shows the spatial data multiple times for each column in the attribute table.  How do I get the plot to only plot once so that I can add more layers to the map?

Here is the code:

```
UpCarson <- read_sf("UpperCarson.shp")
Gage_L <- read_sf("GageLoc.shp")
extent(UpCarson)
plot(UpCarson, col= NA, border = 'black')
plot(Gage_L, add = TRUE)
```

The plot looks like this...
[image: Shapefile plotted multiple times, not just once. I am unable to add additional layers to this plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not telling the function which attribute to plot, you can do this with a bracket `plot(UpCarson["tnmid"])` If you don't need the plot symbolized by an attribute you can simply call the geometry `plot(st_geometry(UpCarson))`